# Can "who" function as a conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, relative-pronouns

My teacher told me that "**who**", in the following, functions as a conjunction.

> The one **who** is teaching now is my brother

And functions as a relative pronoun in the following:

> A man **who** lives here

To me, they both look like relative pronouns. Can someone explain how to tell them apart?

Comment: You are right. "Who" is a relative pronoun in both examples. In the first it refers to "one" and in the second to "man". Note that "who" is not a conjunction in any construction.

Comment: From Wikipedia (FWIW): "The concept of complementizers is specific to certain modern grammatical theories; in traditional grammar, ***such words are normally considered conjunctions***." There's no citation there. Leaving it here for interest.

Comment: Yes, some people use the term complementizer instead of conjunction when it introduces complement clauses. But relative clauses are modifiers, not complements, so the use of that term is misplaced here.